# println within a scala class does not show output on STDOUT

Tags: java, scala, class, object, println

I found this code on tutorialspoint. Code looks very straight forward. It calls the move method from class point. That method print the new x/y coordinates on STDOUT. But, it does not and I cannot figure out why. I ran the code both on scala on cygwin and also on spark-shell on cloudera VM. Same result :-)

Grateful if someone could point out (no pun intended) what I am doing wrong.

`class_plus.scala`:

```
import java.io._

class Point(val xc: Int, val yc: Int) {
   var x: Int = xc
   var y: Int = yc
     def move(dx: Int, dy: Int) {
     x = x + dx
     y = y + dy
     println ("Point x location : " + x);
     println ("Point y location : " + y);
  }
 }

  object Test {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val pt = new Point(10, 20);

     // Move to a new location
     pt.move(10, 10);
   }
  }
```

Then I run:

```
  u0124587@U0124587-TPL-B ~
  $ scala class_plus.scala

  u0124587@U0124587-TPL-B ~
  $
```

Comment: Are you calling the Test object somewhere?

Comment: no. How do I do that? Apologies for being a dummy.

Comment: What Steve answered is what I was suggesting that you were missing ;) Sorry I didn't have time to write a complete answer. Glad it's working now.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!, @hasumedic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your main method is not being executed. If you add this line to the bottom of your file to explicitly invoke the main method it should work:

```
Test.main(args)
```

To get the main method inside Test to work as an entry point in the way that you are expecting without adding that extra line, you will need to compile the file to a class first:

```
scalac class_plus.scala
```

This will create a couple of class files in the same directory, and you you can then run

```
scala Test
```

which should give you the output that you are expecting